# How to share sites using ACL to another user in Google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am a admin user. I want to share sites to another user, even out of my domain using google apps script. I have tried with ACL and used the following code:

```
function shareSite(){


  var base = 'https://sites.google.com/feeds/';
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('google', base);
  fetchArgs.method = 'POST'
  var rawXml = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>"
      +"<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' "
      +"term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>"
      +"<gAcl:role value='owner'/>"
      +"<gAcl:scope type='user' value='newOwnerEmail'/>"
      +"</entry>";

  fetchArgs.payload = rawXml;
  fetchArgs.contentType = 'application/atom+xml';
  var url=base+'/acl/site/<domain-name>/<site-name>'
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText(); 
  Logger.log(content)
}

//Google oAuth
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
   oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("");
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always",
  Host: 'sites.google.com',
  Authorization: 'OAuth',
  oauth_version:"1.0",
  oauth_nonce:"",
  oauth_timestamp:"",
  oauth_consumer_key:"",
  oauth_token:"",
  oauth_signature_method:"HMAC-SHA1", 
  oauth_signature:""};
}
```

I have tried this code, its gives 400(Bad Request) and some times gives 404(Site not found).
Expected server response would be 201.
If any have know its solution and another way to do this then please share with me.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the built-in SitesApp service to modify the ACLs. `Site.addCollaborator()` should do what you want.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_site#addCollaborator